# How to query for objects tracked by LFS on github or any other remote

Tags: git-lfs

Looking over the docs and trying some semi-random commands, I couldn't find a way to use `git lfs` to query for objects that were tracked by LFS.

Locally, I can just use:

```sh
git lfs ls-files -all
```

Which, interestingly, does give me a list of OIDs (pointers) and their original file name and location, but does not give me the actual location of the large binary files. I can find them only by searching for the OID in the `.git\lfs\objects` dir. i'm not aware of a better way.

Is there a synonym for `lfs ls-files` where I can query the remote?

I'm mainly asking this because I notice a discrepancy between the files tracked by LFS locally and the ones tracked on the remote server. After `git clone` the set of files tracked by LFS is far larger than the files that I can find manually having an OID pointer on the Github server. I'm trying to understand why this discrepancy exists.

Comment: Note that Git proper (the part that does not include the LFS wrappers) is entirely unaware of the notion of a "pointer file". Git is being told that the pointer files *are* the source files. The LFS wrappers are secretly storing the data you want to use elsewhere, and lying to Git about this. So only the LFS wrappers can tell which files are replaced by pointer-files in the repository. (Whether LFS servers have a way to help you out, I have no idea, but Git literally *can't*.)

Comment: @torek, tx. While that seems to make sense, Github does seem to have a notion of LFS. If a file is tracked, it will show "Stored with Git LFS" and you won't be able to see the OID, instead when you download it will download the file from the LFS storage (wherever that is). Still, I understand what you're saying that Git, by design, is largely unaware of LFS. The closest I could get is to just clone and check locally.

Comment: Yes, GitHub knows if you're using their LFS servers for their repositories. But that's a GitHub-specific trick. There may be some additional GitHub-specific tricks for querying this. (I don't remember seeing any in glancing at the GitHub API docs but I have never looked that closely at them, and the last time I looked was more than a year ago.)